# Find one repeated word on text file and print that word and the next one

Tags: python

I have this output saved in a text file repeated 4 times:

```
    x.x.x.x/xx         *[BGP/170] 5d 12:05:08, MED 100, localpref 300, from x.x.x.x
                        >  to x.x.x.x via et-0/1/5.0
                        [BGP/170] 5d 12:05:08, MED 100, localpref 300
                        >  to x.x.x.x via et-0/1/5.0
                        [BGP/170] 1w3d 23:49:43, MED 100, localpref 300, from x.x.x.x
                        >  to x.x.x.x via ae0.0
                        [BGP/170] 1w3d 23:49:43, localpref 90
                        >  to x.x.x.x via ae3.0
```

I need to print the word "localpref" and the next one, so I need to have an output like this for all the lines where is present "localpref"

```
    localpref 300
    localpref 300
    localpref 300
    localpref 90
    localpref xx
    localpref xx
    ...
```

I tried with this code:

```
    with open(r'Output.txt', 'r') as LP:
       word = 'localpref'
       all_data = LP.readlines()
       for line in all_data:
           if line.find(word) != -1:
            list_of_words = line
            localpref_and_value = list_of_words[list_of_words.index(word) + 1]
            now = datetime.now()
            print(now)
            print('-'*65)
            print('Local preferences found')
            print({word},{localpref_and_value})
            print('-'*65)
```

But I can only have printed this and I can't understand where is the error:

```
    Local preferences found
    {'localpref'} {'o'}
```

This's my first python code so I'm really new about this, sorry if the code is not clean.
Thanks!

Comment: `list_of_words = line.split()` and `print(word, localpref_and_value)`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I'm feeling really stupid, with your suggestions is working as expected, thanks!

Comment: Cheers! Everyone starts somewhere. Don't sweat it :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant  `print(f"{word},{localpref_and_value}")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text is always semantically the same and the "localpref x" is always in the same relative position of the line, you could use a much shorter attempt:

```
with open(r'Output.txt', 'r') as LP:
    text = LP.readline()
    while text != "": #until the file ends
        if "localpref" in text:
            print( text.split(",")[2].lstrip() ) #print the third comma separated substring
        text = LP.readline()
```

The separation would look like this for one of your provided lines:
`[BGP/170] 5d 12:05:08`, `MED 100`, `localpref 300`.

And, because indexing starts at `0`, you need substring `2`. The only thing left is removing the leading whitespace with `lstrip()`.